# What does "Augenmaß" mean in a political context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've just seen an election poster which says "Verantwortung und Augenmaß" which literally translates into "Responsibility and *quick'n'dirty measurement*".

What does it mean in a political context?

[image]

Comment: Note that "quick'n dirty" has a sense of sloppiness that Augenmaß does not (necessarily) have. It aims for good judgement, whether  you talk about physical measurements or use the term in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: quick'n'dirty measurement in politics? come on

Comment: @Alex I see what you did there...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**[Augenmaß](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Augenmasz)** has two meanings, here the second fits:

> 2. Fähigkeit, in angemessener Weise zu handeln; Besonnenheit, Umsicht
>    Beispiele
>    *das rechte Augenmaß verloren haben
>
>    Politik mit Augenmaß (Besonnenheit, Realitätssinn)*

So a very rough translation would be
"**Responsibility and a sense of good judgement/appropriateness**"

Comment: Ah, easy as that :) I felt like "Yeah, that fits somehow... but why?" It's clear now - thanks.

Comment: @OddDev it might be related to `to eyeball: To measure or estimate roughly by sight`

Comment: i feel like both meanings dont fit :)

Comment: @Alex That's just because you know politicians...

Comment: While (very) close, 'Augenmaß' has a more professional co-notation than 'eyeballing' - Which roughly translates to 'Schätzen'

Answer (score -5):

"**Augenmaß**" means:

Just enough to reach the target, but not more as necessary. Easy said, the people want "**bread and circuses**", give it to them and they calm down.

In political context, it tells that i.e. the government will provide a service which is close to current needs.

Like initiating the infrastructure for free Wifi in city centres. This of course will be handled by telecommunication companies, but the people of a city asked their local politician for something like that, because the politician is closer to the base of people and easier to reach out.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it seems to be more a guess about what politicians actually mean when they say it than what the phrase actually means.

Comment: No, it does not mean "the bare minimum". We are discussing language, not politics. And from a language perspective, this answer is plain wrong.

Comment: **What does it mean in a political context?** it is asked in a political context, or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, no, but you're not telling us what it means in a political context in general, you're making guesses as to what politicians actually mean when they say it. That's not the same thing

Comment: Tough crowd you are...